# "ld: library not found for -lasan" error when specifying "-fsanitize=address" with g++@12 installed by homebrew in x86_64 macOS

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, homebrew, address-sanitizer

The error happens when running g++(gcc@12) with `-fsanitize=address` option.

```
$ g++-12 --std=c++20 -g -fsanitize=address ./main.cpp -o a.out
ld: library not found for -lasan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

## Environment

- macOS Sonoma 14.3.1
- CPU x86_64
- g++-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.3.0) 12.3.0
- Homebrew 4.2.7
- Command line tools path: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk

## What I did

I reinstalled gcc@12 and nothing changed.

I couldn't find libasan.dylib for gcc@12.

```
$ find /usr/local -name "*asan*"
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/lib/clang/17/include/sanitizer/asan_interface.h
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/lib/clang/17/include/sanitizer/hwasan_interface.h
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/lib/clang/17/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_abi_osx.a
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/lib/clang/17/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/lib/clang/17/share/asan_ignorelist.txt
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/13/plugin/include/asan.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@12/12.3.0/lib/gcc/12/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/12/plugin/include/asan.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.5.0/lib/gcc/9/libasan_preinit.o
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.5.0/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21/9.5.0/include/sanitizer/asan_interface.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.5.0/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21/9.5.0/plugin/include/asan.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.5.0/lib/gcc/9/libasan.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@9/9.5.0/lib/gcc/9/libasan.5.dylib
```

```
$ find /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools -name "*asan*"
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include/sanitizer/asan_interface.h
...
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libasan.dylib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_watchossim_dynamic.dylib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_tvossim_dynamic.dylib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/share/asan_ignorelist.txt
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem_asan.tbd
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B_asan.tbd
```

I checked [AddressSanitizer's documentation](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and gcc seems supporting AddressSanitizer in x86_64 OS X.

I checked [the formula of gcc@12](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/g/gcc%4012.rb) and I wonder if it is ok the args don't contain `--enable-libsanitizer`.

Is there something I can try to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sanitizer seems no longer supported in x86_64 macOS (since Ventura).

https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3384#discussioncomment-6264292